# What are the titles of the K-PAX books?

Tags: books, k-pax

I recently read a post about K-PAX and about Prot being an alien or not and I noticed most people were quoting a book (three books to be exact).

I was wondering what the names of these three books were as I'd want to make sure I bought the right "trilogy" so I can read them in order.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @MikeScott: the [was the case](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/328/how-should-we-handle-questions-that-are-easily-answered-by-wikipedia) but I think it [has been rescinded](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/should-we-burninate-general-reference).

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-PAX_(film) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-PAX

Comment: Seems there's a [fourth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-PAX_IV:_A_New_Visitor_from_the_Constellation_Lyra) book.

Comment: @Wikis The "General Reference" close reason got scrapped, but the Help Centre still says: "Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here: Facts easily found on a reference site"

Comment: @MikeScott - OK, so we don't specify "General Reference" but just close as "off-topic"? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something easily searchable

Comment: That seems to be the case for a great deal of the questions answered here. I see no harm in spending 5 minutes answering a simple question, since it proves what a friendly and helpful community this is. :-)

Comment: Almost everything is "easily searchable". We got rid of General reference. It's poorly researched, but we no longer close things for those reasons. It is *not* off-topic. Downvote if you want, and move on.

Comment: @phantom42 - I think there's a difference between "searchable" and "easily searchable". If you google the **question title**, the first ten links give you the answer.

Comment: @Richard That's completely irrelevant. Being easily searchable was the basis for General Reference. Since we no longer have General Reference as a close reason, it's not a valid basis to close it on.

Comment: Aside from the ["Burninated" General Reference](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/should-we-burninate-general-reference), we also do not close questions [for being trivial](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/should-we-close-questions-for-being-too-trivial).

Comment: @phantom42 - This question clearly contravenes "**the following types of questions are off-topic here : Facts easily found on a reference site: Who played X in Y?"**; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Then the FAQ should be updated to reflect meta, because meta-established policy says otherwise.

Comment: Related [meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3537/1027).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The titles, in order, are:

1. K-PAX (1995)
2. K-PAX II: On a Beam of Light (2001)
3. K-PAX III: Worlds of Prot (2002)
4. K-PAX IV: A New Visitor from the Constellation Lyra (2007)

Based on the [Wikipedia article for the first K-PAX book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-PAX).

Comment: Now there’s a [fifth book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-PAX).